# Conditional test around xsl:apply-templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've been trying to learn how to code in xslt and currently am stuck on how to use conditional tests around the xsl:apply-templates tag.

Here's the xml that I am testing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
```

Here is my xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist" />
    <br /> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="country" />
    <br />
    <xsl:if test="country != 'USA' and year != '1985'">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="year" />
    </xsl:if>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="country">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="year">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Here is my output:

```
Bob Dylan
USA

Bonnie Tyler
UK
1988

Dolly Parton
USA
```

Here is the output I was expecting:

```
Bob Dylan
USA

Bonnie Tyler
UK
1988

Dolly Parton
USA
1982
```

Even though I want to remove the year only when country has a value of USA and year has a value of 1985 it is removing the year every time country has a value of USA only.  Is there a better way I can use apply-templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might prefer to apply templates to the wanted node set directly, without conditional "if" check.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="year[not(../country='USA' and ../year='1985)]" />
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had not tried using the not function.  Also thanks for the information on logic.  So far it seems a lot of my errors are related to conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply correct your logic**.

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:if test="country != 'USA' and year != '1985'">
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:if test="country != 'USA' or year != '1985'">
```

**and even better, apply templates only on the wanted nodes**:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "self::*[country != 'USA' or year != '1985']/year"/>
```

**Do note**:

As demonstrated, it is possible to specify the Xpath expression in the `select` attribute without using any reverse axes (going back and forth).

Answer (score 1):

This helped me, thank you.
I was expanding upon this very example and trying to call one template for a certain attribute (I had edited the XML to eg `<artist sex="male">Bob Dylan</artist>`
My attempts were failing but i worked it out. This code allowed me to create conditional templates in >1 scenario: -

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist [@sex = 'male']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist [@sex = 'female']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist [@sex = 'male']">
    Artist: <span style="color:#e9d419">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist [@sex = 'female']">
    Artist: <span style="color:#48b8ff">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="year">
    Year: <span style="color:#eb47dc">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps and is useful to someone! The output produced the artist name in a different colour depending on their sex.

Answer (score -1):

You want to remove the year if the country is USA and if the year is 1985.

Therefore, you want to copy the year if the country is not USA **or** if the year is not 1985.

Your condition should use an `or` instead of an `and`. Note that `not(a and b) = (not a) or (not b)`.

Comment: Logic tells us that `not (A and B)=not A or not B`. This is known in logic as DeMorgan's Laws.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I've gotten pretty familiar with using the call-template tag and for-each but in reading about xslt it seems that a lot of people prefer apply-templates so I've been working to understand that better.  Thanks again.

Comment: @empo: Thanks for pointing out the missing `not` in the formula ... I should had left the solution as it was before I added the third line ;-)